# in twitter api I want to know the number of tweets that match specific query

Tags: search, twitter

the problem is they limit the result they return to 1,500.

but I only want to know how many results there are, not to get all of them

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know this without using the [Streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api) to track the keywords you want an maintaining your own count. The [Search API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) only contains data for about the last 7-14 days depending on tweet volume so even if you did paginate through all available tweets you would only have a recent count.

Comment: This answer still holds true 10 years later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Twitter Count API:

```
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=www.apple.com&callback=twttr.receiveCount
```

Response:

```
twttr.receiveCount({"count":2596822,"url":"http://www.apple.com/"})
```

Note: this is not officially support by Twitter, so use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty easy tutorial on [grabbing Tweet counts](http://www.w3avenue.com/2010/02/24/how-to-get-digg-delicious-and-tweet-counts-using-jquery/) why you can do using JSON and the TweetMeme API.

`$.getJSON('http://api.tweetmeme.com/url_info.jsonc?url='+url+'&amp;callback=?',
    function(data) {
        $('#twitter').append(beforecounter + data.story.url_count + aftercounter);
});`

where the **url** variable corresponds to the url in the query you are matching.